# Website not functioning correctly, when clicking onto for example checkout

Tags: jquery

I have a website gsstickerman.co.uk

But when you click onto checkout for example, nothing happens. Before it came up with the checkout box. I looked in the java console

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'touchstart' of undefined"
The code related to this error:

```
//  jQuery Mobile framework customized for Camera slideshow, made by
//  'jquery.mobile.define.js',
//  'jquery.ui.widget.js',
//  'jquery.mobile.widget.js',
//  'jquery.mobile.media.js',
//  'jquery.mobile.support.js',
//  'jquery.mobile.vmouse.js',
//  'jquery.mobile.event.js',
//  'jquery.mobile.core.js'
window.define=function(){Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).pop()(window.jQuery)};define(["jquery"],function(a){(function(a,b){if(a.cleanData){var c=a.cleanData;a.cleanData=function(b){for(var d=0,e;(e=b[d])!=null;d++){a(e).triggerHandler("remove")}c(b)}}else{var d=a.fn.remove;a.fn.remove=function(b,c){return this.each(function(){if(!c){if(!b||a.filter(b,[this]).length){a("*",this).add([this]).each(function(){a(this).triggerHandler("remove")})}}return d.call(a(this),b,c)})}}a.widget=function(b,c,d){var e=b.split(".")[0],f;b=b.split(".")[1];f=e+"-"+b;if(!d){d=c;c=a.Widget}a.expr[":"][f]=function(c){return!!a.data(c,b)};a[e]=a[e]||{};a[e][b]=function(a,b){if(arguments.length){this._createWidget(a,b)}};var g=new c;g.options=a.extend(true,{},g.options);a[e][b].prototype=a.extend(true,g,{namespace:e,widgetName:b,widgetEventPrefix:a[e][b].prototype.widgetEventPrefix||b,widgetBaseClass:f},d);a.widget.bridge(b,a[e][b])};a.widget.bridge=function(c,d){a.fn[c]=function(e){var f=typeof e==="string",g=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1),h=this;e=!f&&g.length?a.extend.apply(null,[true,e].concat(g)):e;if(f&&e.charAt(0)==="_"){return h}if(f){this.each(function(){var d=a.data(this,c);if(!d){throw"cannot call methods on "+c+" prior to initialization; "+"attempted to call method '"+e+"'"}if(!a.isFunction(d[e])){throw"no such method '"+e+"' for "+c+" widget instance"}var f=d[e].apply(d,g);if(f!==d&&f!==b){h=f;return false}})}else{this.each(function(){var b=a.data(this,c);if(b){b.option(e||{})._init()}else{a.data(this,c,new d(e,this))}})}return h}};a.Widget=function(a,b){if(arguments.length){this._createWidget(a,b)}};a.Widget.prototype={widgetName:"widget",widgetEventPrefix:"",options:{disabled:false},_createWidget:function(b,c){a.data(c,this.widgetName,this);this.element=a(c);this.options=a.extend(true,{},this.options,this._getCreateOptions(),b);var d=this;this.element.bind("remove."+this.widgetName,function(){d.destroy()});this._create();this._trigger("create");this._init()},_getCreateOptions:function(){var b={};if(a.metadata){b=a.metadata.get(element)[this.widgetName]}return b},_create:function(){},_init:function(){},destroy:function(){this.element.unbind("."+this.widgetName).removeData(this.widgetName);this.widget().unbind("."+this.widgetName).removeAttr("aria-disabled").removeClass(this.widgetBaseClass+"-disabled "+"ui-state-disabled")},widget:function(){return this.element},option:function(c,d){var e=c;if(arguments.length===0){return a.extend({},this.options)}if(typeof c==="string"){if(d===b){return this.options[c]}e={};e[c]=d}this._setOptions(e);return this},_setOptions:function(b){var c=this;a.each(b,function(a,b){c._setOption(a,b)});return this},_setOption:function(a,b){this.options[a]=b;if(a==="disabled"){this.widget()[b?"addClass":"removeClass"](this.widgetBaseClass+"-disabled"+" "+"ui-state-disabled").attr("aria-disabled",b)}return this},enable:function(){return this._setOption("disabled",false)},disable:function(){return this._setOption("disabled",true)},_trigger:function(b,c,d){var e=this.options[b];c=a.Event(c);c.type=(b===this.widgetEventPrefix?b:this.widgetEventPrefix+b).toLowerCase();d=d||{};if(c.originalEvent){for(var f=a.event.props.length,g;f;){g=a.event.props[--f];c[g]=c.originalEvent[g]}}this.element.trigger(c,d);return!(a.isFunction(e)&&e.call(this.element[0],c,d)===false||c.isDefaultPrevented())}}})(jQuery)});define(["jquery","./jquery.ui.widget"],function(a){(function(a,b){a.widget("mobile.widget",{_createWidget:function(){a.Widget.prototype._createWidget.apply(this,arguments);this._trigger("init")},_getCreateOptions:function(){var c=this.element,d={};a.each(this.options,function(a){var e=c.jqmData(a.replace(/[A-Z]/g,function(a){return"-"+a.toLowerCase()}));if(e!==b){d[a]=e}});return d},enhanceWithin:function(b){var c=a.mobile.closestPageData(a(b)),d=c&&c.keepNativeSelector()||"";a(this.options.initSelector,b).not(d)[this.widgetName]()}})})(jQuery)});define(["jquery","./jquery.mobile.core"],function(a){(function(a,b){var c=a(window),d=a("html");a.mobile.media=function(){var b={},c=a("<div id='jquery-mediatest'>"),e=a("<body>").append(c);return function(a){if(!(a in b)){var f=document.createElement("style"),g="@media "+a+" { #jquery-mediatest { position:absolute; } }";f.type="text/css";if(f.styleSheet){f.styleSheet.cssText=g}else{f.appendChild(document.createTextNode(g))}d.prepend(e).prepend(f);b[a]=c.css("position")==="absolute";e.add(f).remove()}return b[a]}}()})(jQuery)});define(["jquery","./jquery.mobile.media"],function(a){(function(a,b){function m(){var b=location.protocol+"//"+location.host+location.pathname+"ui-dir/",d=a("head base"),e=null,f="",g,h;if(!d.length){d=e=a("<base>",{href:b}).appendTo("head")}else{f=d.attr("href")}g=a("<a href='testurl' />").prependTo(c);h=g[0].href;d[0].href=f||location.pathname;if(e){e.remove()}return h.indexOf(b)===0}function l(){var b="transform-3d";return k("perspective","10px","moz")||a.mobile.media("(-"+e.join("-"+b+"),(-")+"-"+b+"),("+b+")")}function k(a,b,c){var d=document.createElement("div"),f=function(a){return a.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+a.substr(1)},g=function(a){return"-"+a.charAt(0).toLowerCase()+a.substr(1)+"-"},h=function(c){var e=g(c)+a+": "+b+";",h=f(c),i=h+f(a);d.setAttribute("style",e);if(!!d.style[i]){k=true}},j=c?[c]:e,k;for(i=0;i<j.length;i++){h(j[i])}return!!k}function j(a){var c=a.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+a.substr(1),f=(a+" "+e.join(c+" ")+c).split(" ");for(var g in f){if(d[f[g]]!==b){return true}}}var c=a("<body>").prependTo("html"),d=c[0].style,e=["Webkit","Moz","O"],f="palmGetResource"in window,g=window.operamini&&{}.toString.call(window.operamini)==="[object OperaMini]",h=window.blackberry;a.extend(a.mobile,{browser:{}});a.mobile.browser.ie=function(){var a=3,b=document.createElement("div"),c=b.all||[];while(b.innerHTML="<!--[if gt IE "+ ++a+"]><br><![endif]-->",c[0]){}return a>4?a:!a}();a.extend(a.support,{orientation:"orientation"in window&&"onorientationchange"in window,touch:"ontouchend"in document,cssTransitions:"WebKitTransitionEvent"in window||k("transition","height 100ms linear"),pushState:"pushState"in history&&"replaceState"in history,mediaquery:a.mobile.media("only all"),cssPseudoElement:!!j("content"),touchOverflow:!!j("overflowScrolling"),cssTransform3d:l(),boxShadow:!!j("boxShadow")&&!h,scrollTop:("pageXOffset"in window||"scrollTop"in document.documentElement||"scrollTop"in c[0])&&!f&&!g,dynamicBaseTag:m()});c.remove();var n=function(){var a=window.navigator.userAgent;return a.indexOf("Nokia")>-1&&(a.indexOf("Symbian/3")>-1||a.indexOf("Series60/5")>-1)&&a.indexOf("AppleWebKit")>-1&&a.match(/(BrowserNG|NokiaBrowser)\/7\.[0-3]/)}();a.mobile.ajaxBlacklist=window.blackberry&&!window.WebKitPoint||g||n;if(n){a(function(){a("head link[rel='stylesheet']").attr("rel","alternate stylesheet").attr("rel","stylesheet")})}if(!a.support.boxShadow){a("html").addClass("ui-mobile-nosupport-boxshadow")}})(jQuery)});define(["jquery"],function(a){(function(a,b,c,d){function O(b){var c=b.substr(1);return{setup:function(d,f){if(!M(this)){a.data(this,e,{})}var g=a.data(this,e);g[b]=true;k[b]=(k[b]||0)+1;if(k[b]===1){t.bind(c,H)}a(this).bind(c,N);if(s){k["touchstart"]=(k["touchstart"]||0)+1;if(k["touchstart"]===1){t.bind("touchstart",I).bind("touchend",L).bind("touchmove",K).bind("scroll",J)}}},teardown:function(d,f){--k[b];if(!k[b]){t.unbind(c,H)}if(s){--k["touchstart"];if(!k["touchstart"]){t.unbind("touchstart",I).unbind("touchmove",K).unbind("touchend",L).unbind("scroll",J)}}var g=a(this),h=a.data(this,e);if(h){h[b]=false}g.unbind(c,N);if(!M(this)){g.removeData(e)}}}}function N(){}function M(b){var c=a.data(b,e),d;if(c){for(d in c){if(c[d]){return true}}}return false}function L(a){if(r){return}B();var b=y(a.target),c;G("vmouseup",a,b);if(!o){var d=G("vclick",a,b);if(d&&d.isDefaultPrevented()){c=w(a).changedTouches[0];p.push({touchID:v,x:c.clientX,y:c.clientY});q=true}}G("vmouseout",a,b);o=false;E()}function K(b){if(r){return}var c=w(b).touches[0],d=o,e=a.vmouse.moveDistanceThreshold;o=o||Math.abs(c.pageX-m)>e||Math.abs(c.pageY-n)>e,flags=y(b.target);if(o&&!d){G("vmousecancel",b,flags)}G("vmousemove",b,flags);E()}function J(a){if(r){return}if(!o){G("vmousecancel",a,y(a.target))}o=true;E()}function I(b){var c=w(b).touches,d,e;if(c&&c.length===1){d=b.target;e=y(d);if(e.hasVirtualBinding){v=u++;a.data(d,f,v);F();D();o=false;var g=w(b).touches[0];m=g.pageX;n=g.pageY;G("vmouseover",b,e);G("vmousedown",b,e)}}}function H(b){var c=a.data(b.target,f);if(!q&&(!v||v!==c)){var d=G("v"+b.type,b);if(d){if(d.isDefaultPrevented()){b.preventDefault()}if(d.isPropagationStopped()){b.stopPropagation()}if(d.isImmediatePropagationStopped()){b.stopImmediatePropagation()}}}}function G(b,c,d){var e;if(d&&d[b]||!d&&z(c.target,b)){e=x(c,b);a(c.target).trigger(e)}return e}function F(){if(l){clearTimeout(l);l=0}}function E(){F();l=setTimeout(function(){l=0;C()},a.vmouse.resetTimerDuration)}function D(){A()}function C(){v=0;p.length=0;q=false;B()}function B(){r=true}function A(){r=false}function z(b,c){var d;while(b){d=a.data(b,e);if(d&&(!c||d[c])){return b}b=b.parentNode}return null}function y(b){var c={},d,f;while(b){d=a.data(b,e);for(f in d){if(d[f]){c[f]=c.hasVirtualBinding=true}}b=b.parentNode}return c}function x(b,c){var e=b.type,f,g,i,k,l,m,n,o;b=a.Event(b);b.type=c;f=b.originalEvent;g=a.event.props;if(e.search(/mouse/)>-1){g=j}if(f){for(n=g.length,k;n;){k=g[--n];b[k]=f[k]}}if(e.search(/mouse(down|up)|click/)>-1&&!b.which){b.which=1}if(e.search(/^touch/)!==-1){i=w(f);e=i.touches;l=i.changedTouches;m=e&&e.length?e[0]:l&&l.length?l[0]:d;if(m){for(o=0,len=h.length;o<len;o++){k=h[o];b[k]=m[k]}}}return b}function w(a){while(a&&typeof a.originalEvent!=="undefined"){a=a.originalEvent}return a}var e="virtualMouseBindings",f="virtualTouchID",g="vmouseover vmousedown vmousemove vmouseup vclick vmouseout vmousecancel".split(" "),h="clientX clientY pageX pageY screenX screenY".split(" "),i=a.event.mouseHooks?a.event.mouseHooks.props:[],j=a.event.props.concat(i),k={},l=0,m=0,n=0,o=false,p=[],q=false,r=false,s="addEventListener"in c,t=a(c),u=1,v=0;a.vmouse={moveDistanceThreshold:10,clickDistanceThreshold:10,resetTimerDuration:1500};for(var P=0;P<g.length;P++){a.event.special[g[P]]=O(g[P])}if(s){c.addEventListener("click",function(b){var c=p.length,d=b.target,e,g,h,i,j,k;if(c){e=b.clientX;g=b.clientY;threshold=a.vmouse.clickDistanceThreshold;h=d;while(h){for(i=0;i<c;i++){j=p[i];k=0;if(h===d&&Math.abs(j.x-e)<threshold&&Math.abs(j.y-g)<threshold||a.data(h,f)===j.touchID){b.preventDefault();b.stopPropagation();return}}h=h.parentNode}}},true)}})(jQuery,window,document)});define(["jquery","./jquery.mobile.core","./jquery.mobile.media","./jquery.mobile.support","./jquery.mobile.vmouse"],function(a){(function(a,b,c){function i(b,c,d){var e=d.type;d.type=c;a.event.handle.call(b,d);d.type=e}a.each(("touchstart touchmove touchend orientationchange throttledresize "+"tap taphold swipe swipeleft swiperight scrollstart scrollstop").split(" "),function(b,c){a.fn[c]=function(a){return a?this.bind(c,a):this.trigger(c)};a.attrFn[c]=true});var d=a.support.touch,e="touchmove scroll",f=d?"touchstart":"mousedown",g=d?"touchend":"mouseup",h=d?"touchmove":"mousemove";a.event.special.scrollstart={enabled:true,setup:function(){function g(a,c){d=c;i(b,d?"scrollstart":"scrollstop",a)}var b=this,c=a(b),d,f;c.bind(e,function(b){if(!a.event.special.scrollstart.enabled){return}if(!d){g(b,true)}clearTimeout(f);f=setTimeout(function(){g(b,false)},50)})}};a.event.special.tap={setup:function(){var b=this,c=a(b);c.bind("vmousedown",function(d){function k(a){j();if(e==a.target){i(b,"tap",a)}}function j(){h();c.unbind("vclick",k).unbind("vmouseup",h);a(document).unbind("vmousecancel",j)}function h(){clearTimeout(g)}if(d.which&&d.which!==1){return false}var e=d.target,f=d.originalEvent,g;c.bind("vmouseup",h).bind("vclick",k);a(document).bind("vmousecancel",j);g=setTimeout(function(){i(b,"taphold",a.Event("taphold"))},750)})}};a.event.special.swipe={scrollSupressionThreshold:10,durationThreshold:1e3,horizontalDistanceThreshold:30,verticalDistanceThreshold:75,setup:function(){var b=this,d=a(b);d.bind(f,function(b){function j(b){if(!f){return}var c=b.originalEvent.touches?b.originalEvent.touches[0]:b;i={time:(new Date).getTime(),coords:[c.pageX,c.pageY]};if(Math.abs(f.coords[0]-i.coords[0])>a.event.special.swipe.scrollSupressionThreshold){b.preventDefault()}}var e=b.originalEvent.touches?b.originalEvent.touches[0]:b,f={time:(new Date).getTime(),coords:[e.pageX,e.pageY],origin:a(b.target)},i;d.bind(h,j).one(g,function(b){d.unbind(h,j);if(f&&i){if(i.time-f.time<a.event.special.swipe.durationThreshold&&Math.abs(f.coords[0]-i.coords[0])>a.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold&&Math.abs(f.coords[1]-i.coords[1])<a.event.special.swipe.verticalDistanceThreshold){f.origin.trigger("swipe").trigger(f.coords[0]>i.coords[0]?"swipeleft":"swiperight")}}f=i=c})})}};(function(a,b){function j(){var a=e();if(a!==f){f=a;c.trigger("orientationchange")}}var c=a(b),d,e,f,g,h,i={0:true,180:true};if(a.support.orientation){g=a.mobile.media("all and (orientation: landscape)");h=i[b.orientation];if(g&&h||!g&&!h){i={"-90":true,90:true}}}a.event.special.orientationchange=d={setup:function(){if(a.support.orientation&&a.mobile.orientationChangeEnabled){return false}f=e();c.bind("throttledresize",j)},teardown:function(){if(a.support.orientation&&a.mobile.orientationChangeEnabled){return false}c.unbind("throttledresize",j)},add:function(a){var b=a.handler;a.handler=function(a){a.orientation=e();return b.apply(this,arguments)}}};a.event.special.orientationchange.orientation=e=function(){var c=true,d=document.documentElement;if(a.support.orientation){c=i[b.orientation]}else{c=d&&d.clientWidth/d.clientHeight<1.1}return c?"portrait":"landscape"}})(jQuery,b);(function(){a.event.special.throttledresize={setup:function(){a(this).bind("resize",c)},teardown:function(){a(this).unbind("resize",c)}};var b=250,c=function(){f=(new Date).getTime();g=f-d;if(g>=b){d=f;a(this).trigger("throttledresize")}else{if(e){clearTimeout(e)}e=setTimeout(c,b-g)}},d=0,e,f,g})();a.each({scrollstop:"scrollstart",taphold:"tap",swipeleft:"swipe",swiperight:"swipe"},function(b,c){a.event.special[b]={setup:function(){a(this).bind(c,a.noop)}}})})(jQuery,this)});define(["jquery","../external/requirejs/text!../version.txt","./jquery.mobile.widget"],function(a,b){(function(a,c,d){var e={};a.mobile=a.extend({},{version:b,ns:"",subPageUrlKey:"ui-page",activePageClass:"ui-page-active",activeBtnClass:"ui-btn-active",focusClass:"ui-focus",ajaxEnabled:true,hashListeningEnabled:true,linkBindingEnabled:true,defaultPageTransition:"fade",maxTransitionWidth:false,minScrollBack:10,touchOverflowEnabled:false,defaultDialogTransition:"pop",loadingMessage:"loading",pageLoadErrorMessage:"Error Loading Page",loadingMessageTextVisible:false,loadingMessageTheme:"a",pageLoadErrorMessageTheme:"e",autoInitializePage:true,pushStateEnabled:true,orientationChangeEnabled:true,gradeA:function(){return a.support.mediaquery||a.mobile.browser.ie&&a.mobile.browser.ie>=7},keyCode:{ALT:18,BACKSPACE:8,CAPS_LOCK:20,COMMA:188,COMMAND:91,COMMAND_LEFT:91,COMMAND_RIGHT:93,CONTROL:17,DELETE:46,DOWN:40,END:35,ENTER:13,ESCAPE:27,HOME:36,INSERT:45,LEFT:37,MENU:93,NUMPAD_ADD:107,NUMPAD_DECIMAL:110,NUMPAD_DIVIDE:111,NUMPAD_ENTER:108,NUMPAD_MULTIPLY:106,NUMPAD_SUBTRACT:109,PAGE_DOWN:34,PAGE_UP:33,PERIOD:190,RIGHT:39,SHIFT:16,SPACE:32,TAB:9,UP:38,WINDOWS:91},silentScroll:function(b){if(a.type(b)!=="number"){b=a.mobile.defaultHomeScroll}a.event.special.scrollstart.enabled=false;setTimeout(function(){c.scrollTo(0,b);a(document).trigger("silentscroll",{x:0,y:b})},20);setTimeout(function(){a.event.special.scrollstart.enabled=true},150)},nsNormalizeDict:e,nsNormalize:function(b){if(!b){return}return e[b]||(e[b]=a.camelCase(a.mobile.ns+b))},getInheritedTheme:function(a,b){var c=a[0],d="",e=/ui-(bar|body)-([a-z])\b/,f,g;while(c){var f=c.className||"";if((g=e.exec(f))&&(d=g[2])){break}c=c.parentNode}return d||b||"a"},closestPageData:function(a){return a.closest(':jqmData(role="page"), :jqmData(role="dialog")').data("page")}},a.mobile);a.fn.jqmData=function(b,c){var d;if(typeof b!="undefined"){d=this.data(b?a.mobile.nsNormalize(b):b,c)}return d};a.jqmData=function(b,c,d){var e;if(typeof c!="undefined"){e=a.data(b,c?a.mobile.nsNormalize(c):c,d)}return e};a.fn.jqmRemoveData=function(b){return this.removeData(a.mobile.nsNormalize(b))};a.jqmRemoveData=function(b,c){return a.removeData(b,a.mobile.nsNormalize(c))};a.fn.removeWithDependents=function(){a.removeWithDependents(this)};a.removeWithDependents=function(b){var c=a(b);(c.jqmData("dependents")||a()).remove();c.remove()};a.fn.addDependents=function(b){a.addDependents(a(this),b)};a.addDependents=function(b,c){var d=a(b).jqmData("dependents")||a();a(b).jqmData("dependents",a.merge(d,c))};a.fn.getEncodedText=function(){return a("<div/>").text(a(this).text()).html()};var f=a.find,g=/:jqmData\(([^)]*)\)/g;a.find=function(b,c,d,e){b=b.replace(g,"[data-"+(a.mobile.ns||"")+"$1]");return f.call(this,b,c,d,e)};a.extend(a.find,f);a.find.matches=function(b,c){return a.find(b,null,null,c)};a.find.matchesSelector=function(b,c){return a.find(c,null,null,[b]).length>0}})(jQuery,this)})
```

And the other error is
"Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).superfish is not a function"

```
/*
 * jQuery Superfish Menu Plugin - v1.7.4
 * Copyright (c) 2013 Joel Birch
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *  http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 */

;(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    var methods = (function () {
        // private properties and methods go here
        var c = {
                bcClass: 'sf-breadcrumb',
                menuClass: 'sf-js-enabled',
                anchorClass: 'sf-with-ul',
                menuArrowClass: 'sf-arrows'
            },
            ios = (function () {
                var ios = /iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
                if (ios) {
                    // iOS clicks only bubble as far as body children
                    $(window).load(function () {
                        $('body').children().on('click', $.noop);
                    });
                }
                return ios;
            })(),
            wp7 = (function () {
                var style = document.documentElement.style;
                return ('behavior' in style && 'fill' in style && /iemobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent));
            })(),
            toggleMenuClasses = function ($menu, o) {
                var classes = c.menuClass;
                if (o.cssArrows) {
                    classes += ' ' + c.menuArrowClass;
                }
                $menu.toggleClass(classes);
            },
            setPathToCurrent = function ($menu, o) {
                return $menu.find('li.' + o.pathClass).slice(0, o.pathLevels)
                    .addClass(o.hoverClass + ' ' + c.bcClass)
                        .filter(function () {
                            return ($(this).children(o.popUpSelector).hide().show().length);
                        }).removeClass(o.pathClass);
            },
            toggleAnchorClass = function ($li) {
                $li.children('a').toggleClass(c.anchorClass);
            },
            toggleTouchAction = function ($menu) {
                var touchAction = $menu.css('ms-touch-action');
                touchAction = (touchAction === 'pan-y') ? 'auto' : 'pan-y';
                $menu.css('ms-touch-action', touchAction);
            },
            applyHandlers = function ($menu, o) {
                var targets = 'li:has(' + o.popUpSelector + ')';
                if ($.fn.hoverIntent && !o.disableHI) {
                    $menu.hoverIntent(over, out, targets);
                }
                else {
                    $menu
                        .on('mouseenter.superfish', targets, over)
                        .on('mouseleave.superfish', targets, out);
                }
                var touchevent = 'MSPointerDown.superfish';
                if (!ios) {
                    touchevent += ' touchend.superfish';
                }
                if (wp7) {
                    touchevent += ' mousedown.superfish';
                }
                $menu
                    .on('focusin.superfish', 'li', over)
                    .on('focusout.superfish', 'li', out)
                    .on(touchevent, 'a', o, touchHandler);
            },
            touchHandler = function (e) {
                var $this = $(this),
                    $ul = $this.siblings(e.data.popUpSelector);

                if ($ul.length > 0 && $ul.is(':hidden')) {
                    $this.one('click.superfish', false);
                    if (e.type === 'MSPointerDown') {
                        $this.trigger('focus');
                    } else {
                        $.proxy(over, $this.parent('li'))();
                    }
                }
            },
            over = function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    o = getOptions($this);
                clearTimeout(o.sfTimer);
                $this.siblings().superfish('hide').end().superfish('show');
            },
            out = function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    o = getOptions($this);
                if (ios) {
                    $.proxy(close, $this, o)();
                }
                else {
                    clearTimeout(o.sfTimer);
                    o.sfTimer = setTimeout($.proxy(close, $this, o), o.delay);
                }
            },
            close = function (o) {
                o.retainPath = ($.inArray(this[0], o.$path) > -1);
                this.superfish('hide');

                if (!this.parents('.' + o.hoverClass).length) {
                    o.onIdle.call(getMenu(this));
                    if (o.$path.length) {
                        $.proxy(over, o.$path)();
                    }
                }
            },
            getMenu = function ($el) {
                return $el.closest('.' + c.menuClass);
            },
            getOptions = function ($el) {
                return getMenu($el).data('sf-options');
            };

        return {
            // public methods
            hide: function (instant) {
                if (this.length) {
                    var $this = this,
                        o = getOptions($this);
                    if (!o) {
                        return this;
                    }
                    var not = (o.retainPath === true) ? o.$path : '',
                        $ul = $this.find('li.' + o.hoverClass).add(this).not(not).removeClass(o.hoverClass).children(o.popUpSelector),
                        speed = o.speedOut;

                    if (instant) {
                        $ul.show();
                        speed = 0;
                    }
                    o.retainPath = false;
                    o.onBeforeHide.call($ul);
                    $ul.stop(true, true).animate(o.animationOut, speed, function () {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        o.onHide.call($this);
                    });
                }
                return this;
            },
            show: function () {
                var o = getOptions(this);
                if (!o) {
                    return this;
                }
                var $this = this.addClass(o.hoverClass),
                    $ul = $this.children(o.popUpSelector);

                o.onBeforeShow.call($ul);
                $ul.stop(true, true).animate(o.animation, o.speed, function () {
                    o.onShow.call($ul);
                });
                return this;
            },
            destroy: function () {
                return this.each(function () {
                    var $this = $(this),
                        o = $this.data('sf-options'),
                        $hasPopUp;
                    if (!o) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    $hasPopUp = $this.find(o.popUpSelector).parent('li');
                    clearTimeout(o.sfTimer);
                    toggleMenuClasses($this, o);
                    toggleAnchorClass($hasPopUp);
                    toggleTouchAction($this);
                    // remove event handlers
                    $this.off('.superfish').off('.hoverIntent');
                    // clear animation's inline display style
                    $hasPopUp.children(o.popUpSelector).attr('style', function (i, style) {
                        return style.replace(/display[^;]+;?/g, '');
                    });
                    // reset 'current' path classes
                    o.$path.removeClass(o.hoverClass + ' ' + c.bcClass).addClass(o.pathClass);
                    $this.find('.' + o.hoverClass).removeClass(o.hoverClass);
                    o.onDestroy.call($this);
                    $this.removeData('sf-options');
                });
            },
            init: function (op) {
                return this.each(function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    if ($this.data('sf-options')) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    var o = $.extend({}, $.fn.superfish.defaults, op),
                        $hasPopUp = $this.find(o.popUpSelector).parent('li');
                    o.$path = setPathToCurrent($this, o);

                    $this.data('sf-options', o);

                    toggleMenuClasses($this, o);
                    toggleAnchorClass($hasPopUp);
                    toggleTouchAction($this);
                    applyHandlers($this, o);

                    $hasPopUp.not('.' + c.bcClass).superfish('hide', true);

                    o.onInit.call(this);
                });
            }
        };
    })();

    $.fn.superfish = function (method, args) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        }
        else if (typeof method === 'object' || ! method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        else {
            return $.error('Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.fn.superfish');
        }
    };

    $.fn.superfish.defaults = {
        popUpSelector: 'ul,.sf-mega', // within menu context
        hoverClass: 'sfHover',
        pathClass: 'overrideThisToUse',
        pathLevels: 1,
        delay: 800,
        animation: {height: 'show'},
        animationOut: {opacity: 'hide'},
        speed: 'normal',
        speedOut: 'fast',
        cssArrows: true,
        disableHI: false,
        onInit: $.noop,
        onBeforeShow: $.noop,
        onShow: $.noop,
        onBeforeHide: $.noop,
        onHide: $.noop,
        onIdle: $.noop,
        onDestroy: $.noop
    };

    // soon to be deprecated
    $.fn.extend({
        hideSuperfishUl: methods.hide,
        showSuperfishUl: methods.show
    });

})(jQuery);

/*---------------------*/
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.sf-menu').superfish()
})
```

Comment: did you found solution ?